# Why does randomForest confusion matrix not match the one I calculate using predictions from the model object?

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm using the R package `randomForest`. When you fit a model, it outputs the confusion matrix, but this completely mismatches what I find when I calculate the confusion matrix based on majority vote myself, using the model predictions. According to the documentation, the default is to use majority vote as the cutoff for classification, so I can't make sense of this.

Here is an example:

```
require(randomForest)
set.seed(1)
y <- runif(500)<.5 
x <- matrix(rnorm(5000),500,10) 
z <- cbind(y,x)
colnames(z) <- c("y",paste("x",c(1:10),sep=""))

rfm <- randomForest( as.factor(y) ~ ., data=z ) 
rfm$confusion

    0   1 class.error
0  81 149   0.6478261
1 101 169   0.3740741

pred <- predict(rfm, z, type="vote", norm.votes=FALSE)[,2]
table(pred>250,y) # there are 500 trees, so >250 is a majority

   y
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE   230    0
  TRUE      0  270
```

Any clue what is going on here?

Comment: In the context of the answer, this thread seems statistical-enough to be considered on topic here, & to stay open, IMO.

Comment: @gung: you do have a point there. I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: To read the question, it sounds like a question about how to use R (ie off topic), @StephanKolassa--I would otherwise have voted w/ you. But your answer (+1 btw) suggests that a statistical confusion underlies the misunderstanding of the documentation. That's my take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the relevant part of the help page `?randomForest`:

```
confusion: (classification only) the confusion matrix of the prediction
          (based on OOB data).
```

Note the second parenthesis. The `confusion` output is derived from the out-of-bag data.

What does this mean? Part of what a random forest does is bootstrap the data, i.e., draw random samples with replacement from the original sample. In each instance, a model is fit to the data drawn. Then this model is applied to predict *the data NOT drawn* (the "out-of-bag" sample). This is a very smart trick to approximate the true expected *out-of-sample* error rate.

In contrast, what your second-to-last line does is that you apply the final model to all data, so you perform an in-sample fitting test. Of course this performs much better. However, in-sample accuracy is *never* a reliable guide to out-of-sample predictive accuracy. So I'd rather trust the `confusion` output of `randomForest()`.

Comment: Thank you!!! So, for each tree that is fit as part of the "forest", some data is withheld? Is it clear how much data is withheld? Is this a "knob" the user can turn?

Comment: The amount of data "withheld" during bootstrapping is nondeterministic (since we sample at random) and can't be tuned. If the original data set has $n$ data points, then in bootstrapping, we sample with replacement $n$ points. So each original point has a chance of $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ of *not* being sampled in any particular bootstrap sample, which converges to $\frac{1}{e}$ as $n\to\infty$. Incidentally, the complement, $1-\frac{1}{e}\approx .632$, is the chance for any particular data point to be *present* in a bootstrap sample. This is the ".632 rule" you will often see in bootstrapping.

Comment: OK. I did not realize that re-sampling with replacement a data set of size $n$ was an inherent part of the algorithm.

Comment: It is. Along with only using a (small) random subset of your predictor variables. Which has *two* cool effects: (1) it reduces the effect of correlations between predictors, (2) it makes training a random forest much faster than training a simple tree with the full set of predictors. Random forests are a neat idea, indeed!